# printing contents of 2d vector

Tags: c++

this is the code I am running:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> test;
test.push_back(std::vector<double>(30));

 std::vector<std::vector<double> >::iterator it=test.begin(), end=test.end();
    while (it!=end) {
      std::vector<double>::iterator it1=it->first.begin(),end1=it->first.end();
      while (it1!=end1) {
    std::copy(it1.begin(),it1.end(),std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
    ++it1;
      }
      ++it;
    }
```

this is the compilation error I get:

```
data.cpp:33:45: error: ‘class std::vector<double>’ has no member named ‘first’
data.cpp:33:68: error: ‘class std::vector<double>’ has no member named ‘first’
data.cpp:35:16: error: ‘class std::vector<double>::iterator’ has no member named ‘begin’
data.cpp:35:28: error: ‘class std::vector<double>::iterator’ has no member named ‘end’
data.cpp:35:34: error: ‘ostream_iterator’ is not a member of ‘std’
data.cpp:35:56: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double'
```

any suggestions on how to fix it so I can print the contents of test

Comment: Minor suggestion: as you're not modifying your 2D vector through iterators but just reading its elements, use `std::vector<double>::const_iterator`

Comment: @BojanKomazec, thanks for the suggestion. I will make the fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more what you want.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> test;
// Put some actual data into the test vector of vectors
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    std::vector<double> random_stuff;
    for(int j = 0; j < 1 + i; ++j)
    {
        random_stuff.push_back(static_cast<double>(rand()) / RAND_MAX);
    }
    test.push_back(random_stuff);
}

std::vector<std::vector<double> >::iterator it=test.begin(), end=test.end();
while (it!=end) 
{
    std::vector<double>::iterator it1=it->begin(),end1=it->end();
    std::copy(it1,end1,std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    ++it;
}
```

You don't want first because your vector doesn't contain pairs, and you don't need to loop based on it1 and end1 because they denote the range you pass to copy.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with the code.

**First** `std::vectors` don't contain `std::pairs`, so there's no `first` or `second`:

```
while (it!=end) {
  std::vector<double>::iterator it1=it->begin(),end1=it->end();
```

**Second** the call to `std::copy` takes a range, which should probably correspond to one of your inner vectors. So you're going one level too deep.

You could iterate over the outer vector `test`, and then print using `copy` for each of it's elements (which is a vector).

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> test;
test.push_back(std::vector<double>(30));
std::vector<std::vector<double> >::iterator it=test.begin(), end=test.end();
for ( it!= end, ++it) {
  std::copy(it1-begin(),it->end(),std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reasoning. for some reason, the for loop gives a compilation error, and changing it to while works.