# How to print vector<vector<string>> in C++?

Tags: c++, printing, iterator

I get some values running a C++ program. say,

```
vector<vector<string>> clusters; // clusters have some values
```

How to print them using iterator ?

Comment: @Arefe You're constantly asking badly layed out/researched questions. Would you consider changing this behavior on SO please??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Just going to ask really quick, how is your name pronounced?

Comment: @BWG It's pronounced [Panta Rei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panta_Rhei) (My real name is Günther Makulik of course!) It's an ancient greek philosophical motto said to come from Heraklit. But actually it's a shortcut for the conclusions on it ...

Comment: possible this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368177/printing-contents-of-2d-vector will be helpful

Comment: I know how to print vector<string> or list<string>. I tried to print when vector<vector<string>> is the data type but didn't work. Can you show me a single question about this ?

Comment: @clcto after I look over years later, I see how dumb as I was at that time. I can't say I become a fine developer by now, but, this was beyond acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully the "use" of iterators doesn't need to be explicit and up-front visible?

```
for( auto const& string_vec : clusters )
    for( auto const& s : string_vec )
        cout << s << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//iterate over our outer vector
for(vector<vector<string> >::iterator it = clusters.begin(); it != clusters.end(); ++it) { 
    //obtain and iterate over the inner vector
    for(vector<string>::iterator it2 = *it.begin(); it2 != *it.end(); ++it2) {
        cout << *it2; //obtain and print our string
    }
}
```

Would this work?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use int as indexes so you can do cout << clusters[i][j] and not have to create a vector variable?

Comment: @JohnOdom It would, definitely. I don't know how to do that with iterators though.

Comment: @JohnOdom just substitute `(*it)` for `v` and then you don't have to create a new one

Comment: use iterator is better and define reference to it: `vector<string>& v = *it;`

Comment: @BWG `it->begin()`, `it->end()`, and if you are using C++11 you can use `auto it = clusters.begin()` :)

Answer (score 1):

The same, but with algorithms:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> VectorVectorString;
typedef VectorVectorString::const_iterator VVSConstIterator;

VectorVectorString clusters;

for(VVSConstIterator pVector = clusters.begin(), end = clusters.end(); pVector != end; ++pVector)
{
    const std::vector<std::string>& current = *pVector;
    std::copy(
        current.begin(), current.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I must ask... how does this work? Do you copy the data to cout, or something?

Comment: it's simple: we have [Stream iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator). It's mean that when you write to the iterator (like with usual iterator: '*it = 10') it's simple write to the stream, in our case to std::cout. Example:
'std::ostream_iterator<std::string> it(std::cout, " ");'
'*it = "10";'
[doc on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)

std::copy has destinition iterator as third argument. And everything  that std::copy do is '*it = value', that, in our case, equal to 'std::cout << value'