# Accessing a Two-Dimensional Set

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I print all elements of 2-dimensional set created as follows?

```
int i, j, n;
set< set<int> > st;
set< set<int> > ::iterator it;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    set<int>row;
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        cin>>n;
        row.insert(n);
    }
    st.insert(row);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printing contents of 2d vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368177/printing-contents-of-2d-vector)

Answer (score 4):

You tagged C++11, so you can use for range loop

```
for ( auto const & s : st )
 {
   for ( auto const & i : s )
      std::cout << i << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: how to access without range loops?

Comment: @Ratnesh apply the normal range-for -> iterator-for translation twice